# Clojure float is not being recognized

Tags: java, functional-programming, clojure

So I am using Clojure to make a simple program that calculates the BMI and returns if the person is healthy or not, based on that calculations.

This is my code

```
(defn bmi [weight height]
(def x (/ weight (Math/pow height 2)))
(println x)

(let [y x]
(cond
  (< y 20.0) "Underweight"
  (< y 25.0 and >= y 20.0) "Normal"
  (< y 30.0 and >= y 25.0) "Obese"
  (< y 40.0 and >= y 30.0) "Obese2"

  :else "Obese3"))
  )

  (bmi 45.0 1.7)
```

I think it is correct, but when I run it it tells me the error.

**CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro: #'clojure.core/and, compiling:(/tmp/form-init8921870265637757493.clj:47:3)**

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some minor comments

- `def` defines "global" variables, you should use `let` to create a "local" value.
- `and` is a macro (you can think of it almost as a function at this point) so it goes on function position (not as an operator in other languages)
- Functions such as `<` can take more than 2 arguments, they return true if the order is preserved (eg. `(< 1 2 3)` returns `true`.

Using the above, you can update your `bmi` function like the following:

```clj
(defn bmi [weight height]
  (let [x (/ weight (Math/pow height 2))]
    (println x)
    (let [y x] ;; You could have used 'x' in the code below too
      (cond
        (< y 20.0) "Underweight"
        (< 20.0 y 25.0) "Normal"
        (< 25.0 y 30.0) "Obese"
        (< 30.0 y 40.0) "Obese2"
        :else "Obese3"))))

;; (bmi 45.0 1.7) ;; => "Underweight"

;; Show `and` over `<` versus plain `<`:
;; (and (< 1 2) (< 2 3)) ;; => true
;; (< 1 2 3) ;; => true
```

Comment: Chaining `<` like this creates unpleasant breakpoints. If `y` is 20, no case will match, and the result will be "Obese3". Instead, just remove the first half of each clause entirely. The clauses above it failed, so we already know in the second clause that `y` is at least 20.

Comment: Good catch, I missed it when removing the `and`s from each test in the `cond`.

Answer (score 2):

`cond` stops when a clause is `true`, so if in the first clause you are looking for
`< 20` in the next one you do not have to look for `>= 20`.
Also, the sintax you are using here is not correct:  `(< y 25.0 and >= y 20.0) "`. This should be `(and (< y 25.0) (>= y 20.0))`, but you do not need the second part as you are using in a cond that goes after (< x 20.0).
And like a previous user said, def defines "global" variables, you should use let to create a "local" value.
`(let [x y])` is not needed, you can continue using `x` because they have the same value.
So, your function should be like this:

```
(defn bmi [weight height]
  (let [x (/ weight (Math/pow height 2))]
    (println x)
    (cond
      (< x 20.0) "Underweight"
      (< x 25.0) "Normal"
      (< x 30.0) "Obese"
      (< x 40.0) "Obese2"
      :else "Obese3")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `and` incorrectly. You wrote e.g.

```
(< y 25.0 and >= y 20.0)
```

It should be written

```
(and (< y 25.0) (>= y 20.0))
```

Also, using `def` in a function to create a global is not good practice. I suggest

```
(defn bmi [weight-kg height-m]
  (/ weight-kg (* height-m height-m)))

(defn bmi-descrip [weight-kg height-m]
  (let [bmi-val  (bmi weight-kg height-m)]
    (println bmi-val)

    (cond
      (< bmi-val 20.0)                         "Underweight"
      (and (< bmi-val 25.0) (>= bmi-val 20.0)) "Normal"
      (and (< bmi-val 30.0) (>= bmi-val 25.0)) "Obese"
      (and (< bmi-val 40.0) (>= bmi-val 30.0)) "Obese2"
      :else                                    "Obese3")))
```